# Exporting dataframe with xlwings without having a index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I have following code:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('Test.xlsx')
sht1 = wb.sheets['Testsheet']
sht1.range('A8').value = df1
```

I have want to export my df1 but without column1 (index column). how do i do this?

Right now it looks like this:

```
Column1 A B C
```

What I want is this:

```
A B C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this via options:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

wb = xw.Book('Test.xlsx')
sht1 = wb.sheets['Testsheet']
sht1.range('A8').options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value = df1
```

See the docs: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html#pandas-dataframe-converter

Comment: I have similar problem. can you help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537847/how-to-get-excel-cell-row-number-of-a-value-using-python

Answer (score 0):

You may select specified column like this:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df1[['A', 'B', 'C']]
```