# How to get excel cell/row number of a value using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

I have dataframe like as shown below

```
val
5
7
17
95
23
45

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

I would like to get the excel cell/index/row number for each of the value

[image]

I was trying something like below but not sure whether I am overcomplicating it

```
for row in range(1,99999):
    for col in range(1,2999999):
        if wb.sheets[1].range((row,col)).value == 5:
            print("The Row is: "+str(row)+" and the column is "+str(col))
        else
            row = row + 1
```

I also tried something like below but doesn't work either

```
wb.sheets[1].range("A9:B500").options(pd.DataFrame).value
```

Basically, I have a list of values and would like **to find out in which column and row do they appear in excel**. Can someone help me please?

I expect my output to be like below. Excel row numbers are extracted/found from excel

[image]

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71537265/4961700

Comment: This is the same as your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the index of pandas dataframes is zero-based and the row numbers of excel worksheets are one-based, therefore, if you would like to solve this issue with pandas

```
df["index"] = df.index.astype(int) + 1
```

is correct. However, note that the picture in your question shows a part of an excel worksheet, which has an active filter applied. The solution presented here works only, if the data in excel is not filtered.

### Update

You can also specify values in [.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html?highlight=isin#pandas.Series.isin) and get their location in terms of row index and column index. The following code prints – as an example – the row index and column index in pandas notation of all `5` and `2` occurrences in the dataframe (because of `isin([5, 2])`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame((
    (2, 5, 8),
    (20, 5, 772),
    (0, 20, 5),
    (2, 0, 0),
    (76, 35, 66),
    (23, 21, 29),
    (5, 55, 88),
    (44, 23, 5),
    (1, 2, 3),
    ), columns=["a", "b", "c"])

cols = df.columns.to_list()
for col in cols:
    filt = df[col].isin([5, 2])
    df_x = df.loc[filt, col]
    for row, val in df_x.items():
        print(f"row index: {row}     column index: {df.columns.get_indexer([col])[0]}")
```

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am encountering some challenge with similar xlwings problem to find and replace data in template excel file. Is this something that you would be able to help me with? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812206/use-python-to-find-and-replace-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most simple solution to get the index row is using this command:

```
df["index"] = df.index.to_list()
```

A new column will be created with the index values. So, you can use this column to format as you want.

```
index
1
2
6
7
10
12
```

Comment: Do you know how can we pass in a list of values and get their corresponding location? Instead of getting location for all values?